# Using grep() in r to find index

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to find whether the values in one string (string1)exist in another VERY LONG (>17000 char) string (string2) and place the indexes in a vector. So far I have

```
vector<-character(length(string1))
for(i in 1:length(string1)){
vector[i]<-grep(string1[i],string2)
}
```

The issue is the code stops if grep can't find a match. How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grepl` to return a TRUE/FALSE index as `grep` return only a value if it is present

```
for(i in 1:length(string1)){
   vector[i] <- grepl(string1[i],string2)
}
```

Or use a `if/else` statement to return NA

```
for(i in 1:length(string1)){
    temp <- grep(string1[i],string2)
    vector[i] <- if(length(temp)==0) NA else temp
}
```

NOTE: If there are many elements to compare, there is a limit in the vectorized approach with `paste`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do.  If you're trying to find which individual characters in `string1` exist in `string2`, then you can't use `[` for indexing and I'm not sure what you're getting as a result.

You can split the strings on characters, then test.  First, make up some data:

```
string1 <- 'abc'
string2 <- sample(letters, 20)
string2 <- paste0(string2, collapse='')
string2
## [1] "iureyxjnvsbtghfozqpl"
```

These elements in `string1` exist in `string2`:

```
unlist(strsplit(string1, '')) %in% unlist(strsplit(string2, ''))
## [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The `b` matches.  To find the positions of the a match, turn it around and use `match`.  To do it for a vector, use `sapply` to loop:

```
sapply(unlist(strsplit(string1, '')), function(x) match(x, unlist(strsplit(string2, ''))))
## a  b  c 
## NA 11 NA
```